# Help with implementing Salesforce Shield Encryption

Tags: shield-encryption

I am trying to enable few standard(Account-name) and custom fields(of type Text area-long) as 'Encrypted' in my Developer edition.

I enabled 'Manage encryption keys' and 'view encrypted data' for User1 and saved values on both Account and custom objects.

I cloned an existing system profile and removed these 2 permissions and assigned it to User2. I am able to see these 2 fields as normal text from User1 and User2

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for the late answer.

Just as an FYI, there is strictly nothing different from an end user perspective when you enable encryption. The "view encrypted data" permission does not apply to shield anymore, it is only available for classic encryption.

If you want to verify that your data is indeed encrypted in the database, you can destroy your tenant secret and you should see the values replaced by "???" as we can't decrypt them anymore.